# NoSql solution to store 20[TB] of data, as vector/array?

Tags: python, nosql

I need to build a system to efficiently store & maintain a huge amount (20 [TB]) of data (and be able to access it in 'vector' form). Here are my dimensions:

`(1) time (given as an integer of the form YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)`

`(2) field (a string of any given length, representing a name of a hospital)`

`(3) instrumentID (an integer representing a uniqueID for the instrument)`

I will need a way to be able to store data individually, meaning, something like:

**STORE** `23789.46 as the data for instrumentID = 5 on field = 'Nhsdg' on time = 20040713113500`

Yet, I would need the following query to to run **FAST**: `give me all instruments for field 'X' on timestamp 'Y'`.

In order to build these systems, I am given 60 duo-core machines (each with 1GB of RAM, 1.5TB disk)

Any recommendation on a suitable NoSQL soltuion (that would ideally work with python)?

**NOTE**: the system will first store historical data (which is roughly 20[TB]). Every day I will add just about 200[MB] at most. I just need a solution that would scale and scale. my use case would be just a simple query: `give me all instruments for field 'X' on timestamp 'Y'`

Comment: WOW. I want to work wherever you do, man. I don't know the first thing about distributed databases, sorry, but I'll come back and check what others said. Wow.

Comment: Are the STORE commands going to come in time-sorted order, or will you need to STORE records in more or less arbitrary input order (like 6 PM then 7 PM then 2 PM etc.)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're looking for a document-based solution instead of a relational database? You have a defined schema, which negates one of the principal "advantages" of NoSQL databases. Assuming that your data would be entered in chronological order (or even if it wouldn't, if all you care about for performance is querying), a simple relational database with a clustered index on `time` and `field` would be able to satisfy that query quickly even with a data set that large.

Comment: @John: the system will first store historical data (which is roughly 20[TB]). Every day I will add just about 200[MB] at most. I just want to write something that would be scalable. As per the data, the history will not be time-sorted, but the 'fresh' (realtime) data will be.

Comment: @Adam: you're talking about 20[TB] here! only the indices building etc would take so long! I need quick inserts and quick retrievals.

Comment: @user540009: You may need to do more investigation into relational databases. Yes, nonclustered indexes on 20TB will be large, but if you have a single clustered index, you're not going to deal with a (relatively) large index, and there's no maintenance. Your only performance degradation would be if you were to insert records out of order once the data set is large. There is no magic bullet, and there are no magic databases; an index (in concept if not in name or particular implementation) is *required* for fast lookups, whether you're talking about a document DB or a relational DB.

Comment: @user540009: You need to realize that relational databases have been around since the 70's, and their technology is very mature, robust, and, yes, *scalable*. Document databases have a place, but that is primarily in storing the sort of data for which they were designed: i.e. documents or objects with no predefined schema, which are ill-suited to the structure of a relational database. Well designed relational databases are *fast*.

Comment: How many distinct field names and instrument IDs do you think there will ultimately be?

Comment: @John: around `20,000 instruments`, `2000 fields`

Comment: @Adam: can you imagine how much time it would take to store 20[TB] of unordered data using a relational DB? a couple of weeks maybe? nothing scalable here.

Comment: @user540009: You may find that you'll find better solutions if you choose them based upon facts and the experience of others, rather than assumptions. I don't mean to condescend, but it seems that you've already come with an answer in mind.

Comment: @Adam: OK, let's hear. How much time do you think this would take (including building the indices)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) scales awesomely and supports many of the indexing features you'd typically find in an RDBMS such as [compound key indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeysIndexes). You can use a compound index on the name and time attributes in your data. Then you can retrieve all instrument readings with a particular name and date range.

[Now in the simple case where you're strictly interested in just that one basic query and nothing else, you can just combine the name and timestamp and call that your key, which would work in any key-value store...]

[HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) is another excellent option. You can use a [composite row key](http://devblog.streamy.com/2009/04/23/hbase-row-key-design-for-paging-limit-offset-queries/) on name and date.

As others have mentioned, you can definitely use a relational database. MySQL & PostgreSQL can certainly handle the load and [table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html) might be desirable in this scenario as well since your dealing with time ranges. You can use bulk loading (and disabling indexes during loading) to decrease insertion time.

Comment: @jspcal: thank you re `MangoDB`. Do you know what is the overhead of MangoDB on a per record or so?

Comment: You have a minimum 16 bytes of actual data (assuming names will be stored using a numerical ID to save space). The [space overhead](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Storage+of+Small+Objects) wouldn't be a huge obstacle, but it is going to take up some space because your records are quite small. You can probably get the most savings by storing all the instrument readings for a (name, date) tuple in one element as opposed to individual elements for each reading (you might need to pre-process your data or stage readings in a temporary db to then aggregate them into your main db).

Comment: @jspcal: `You can probably get the most savings by storing all the instrument readings for a (name, date) tuple in one element`. Yes, this is the way to go. Two questions: 
`(1) since I don't have all the data for all instruments ahead of time, and will need to update every instrument as I read it, will I easily be able to 'update' the `instrumentID` cell in the tuple retrieved using the key (name,date)?`

`(2) how should I store the data for all instruments within one tuple? as a tuple of floats (like array)? as a tuple of binary (packed) data? -- what is the best way`? thanks.

Comment: @jspcal: is it easy to deploy/scale `MangoDB` on 60 duo-core machines (each with 1GB of RAM, 1.5TB disk)

Comment: 1) updates are pretty quick (redis and tokyo cabinet are excellent options as well), but you should benchmark it based on your workset. MondoDB has a fast [push](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push) operation to append to an array which is what your update would consist of. 2) in the case of MongoDB, it recognizes binary JSON, so you could have an array-of-arrays [[inst1, -90.31], [inst2, 208.83]] etc. There are lots of ways to organize it depending on how much flexibility you need with your queries

Comment: @jspcal: thank you. will I also be able to access random cells within the JSON object? if I have only append, then, if the instruments are not processed in order, how will I be able to `insert` them in the right place?  also, is `tokyo` a real NoSQL solutuon? or is it like `sqlite` (in such a case, how does one deal with replication etc)?  any hints if `cassandra` be good for my needs?

Comment: yes 60 is easy to do (it can handle > 1,000 nodes). check out the pages on [sharding and clustering](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding)

Comment: [tokyo cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/) is an ultra-fast key-value store. it is definitely "NoSQL". any of these storage systems can do what you need. there's a comparison [here](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis).

Comment: @jspcal: thank you. Yes, `tokyo cabinet` is "NoSQL", but what I meant was, does it provide replications across nodes etc? or is it just a db in a file?

Comment: also, with `Mango`, suppose I have the following key/value stored:
key = "hello", value = [-90.31,208.83,15.44]. Can I access and replace (in-place) the value that is in the 1st index (208.83), say, with 894.45? (does `Mango` provide random-access as well, not just append)?

Comment: you can use $ ([positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating)) to manipulate array elements at a particular index or use push/addToSet/pop/pull. if the order of readings within a particular (name, time) needs to be queried (not sure why it would be since they're all at the same time), then you can store each reading separately (you'll need a little more space, but it's not a major hit).

Comment: @jspcal: thank you.do you know which one is easier / more robust? (`MangoDB` / `HBase`) to work with from Python? also, is `Mango` really fast? thanks.

Comment: @jspcal: do you know if `Mango` supports 32bit machines (I know some other solutions require 64bit)? any minimal memory requirements per node?

Comment: [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.10%2B/index.html) is quite good. MongoDB uses memory-mapped files, so you can decide how much RAM is used. MongoDB runs on 32-bit, but like most of these systems 64-bit gives better results. Most dual-core CPUs are 64-bit, so I would go with that if possible.