# NoSQL Solution to Store Arrays?

Tags: python, linux, nosql

I need a scalable `NoSql` solution to store data as *arrays* for many fields & time stamps, where the key is a combination of a `field` and a `timestamp`.

Data would be stored in the following scheme:

**KEY** --> "FIELD_NAME.YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS"

**VALUE** --> [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6]                (v1..v6 are just `floats`)

For instance, suppose that:

**FIELD_NAME** = "TOMATO"

**TIME_STAMP** = "20060316.184356"

**VALUES** = [72.34, -22.83, -0.938, 0.265, -2047.23]

I need to be able to retrieve **VALUE** (the entire array) given the combination of `FIELD_NAME` & `TIME_STAMP`.

The query **VALUES**["*TOMATO.20060316.184356*"] would return the vector [72.34, -22.83, -0.938, 0.265, -2047.23]. Reads of arrays should be as fast as possible.

Yet, I also need a way to store (in-place) a scalar value within an array . Suppose that I want to assign the 1st element of `TOMATO` on timestamp `2006/03/16.18:43:56` to be `500.867`. In such a case, I need to have a fast mechanism to do so -- something like:

**VALUES**["*TOMATO.20060316.184356*"][0] = 500.867  (this would update on disk)

Any idea which `NoSql` solution would work best for this(big plus if it has `python` interface)? I am looking for a fast yet a powerful solution. my data needs would grow to about 20[TB].

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoSql solution to store 20\[TB\] of data, as vector/array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560394/nosql-solution-to-store-20tb-of-data-as-vector-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is highly structured and regular; what benefit do you see in NoSQL vs a more traditional database?

I think [MySQL Cluster](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/) sounds tailor-made for your problem.

**Edit:**

@user540009: I agree that there are serious slowdowns on single-machine or mirrored instances of MySQL larger than half a terabyte, and no-one wants to have to deal with manual sharding; MySQL Cluster is meant to deal with this, and I have read of (though not personally played with) implementations up to 110 terabytes.

Comment: there are serious scaling issues with MySQL when you get to such sizes (tens of [TBs]); with NoSql, I can scale horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like MongoDB would be a good fit. [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.10+/index.html) is the api.

Comment: thank you. Do you think it is more suitable than `cassandra`?

Comment: @user540009 I do, yes. But I'm biased. :)